# not able to remove the placeholder using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

i want to remove the *placeholder* once the user on focus the input text field.

```
   $('#keyfob').attr('placeholder','Please click here for Key Fob scanning to work');

        $('#keyfob').attr('placeholder', function () {
            this.toggle = !this.toggle;
            return this.toggle ? $(this).data('placeholder') : "";
        });
    }, 1500);
```

This is the function i am using to show the *blinking* placeholder and keyfob is the field ID and i have return this code on blur event of the field.

so on focus on this field i have to hide or remove the blinking placeholder text.

```
$('#keyfob').attr('placeholder','');
```

This is the function i am using to remove or hide the placeholder,but somehow it is not hiding.

Can anyone help me in solving this issue?

Comment: where's your `HTML`?

Comment: <input type="text" id="keyfob" class="customform col-sm-12 text-red"
    data-required='true'
    placeholder=" Please click here to Key Fob scanning work">

Comment: `$('#keyfob').each(function(){` Wait what? You have multiple elements with the id keyfob?

Comment: Sorry by mistake i have posted the code now i have edited the code can u please see now?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onfocus` and `onblur` events and clear or set the placeholder's text within their respective handler. Try this,

### Solution 1

***HTML :***

```
<input type="text" id="keyfob" class="customform col-sm-12 text-red" data-required='true' placeholder="Please click here to Key Fob scanning work">
```

***jQuery :***

```
$("#keyfob").on("focus", function(){
    previousElement = $(this);
    placeholderText = $(this).attr("placeholder");
    $(this).attr("placeholder", "");
});

$("#keyfob").on("blur", function(){
    $(previousElement).attr("placeholder", placeholderText);
});
```

***Note :***  *If you have multiple `input` elements you just need to refer those using same `class` attribute. This will make everything else work.*

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/p6gf2yo0/)

### Solution 2

If you have a single input element then you can handle it more easily. Try this way,

```
$('#keyfob').on("focus blur", function(){
    $(this).attr("placeholder") == "" ? $(this).attr("placeholder", "Please click here for Key Fob scanning to work") : $(this).attr("placeholder", "");
});
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/kps06mjj/)

### Solution 3

***Updated Code :*** To make the `placeholder` blinking make the content `placeholder` empty and fill it again within a predefined `setInterval`. And `onfocus` use `clearInterval` to clear the blinker `setInterval`.

***jQuery :***

```
previousElement = $("#keyfob");
placeholderText = $("#keyfob").attr("placeholder");

$("#keyfob").on("focus", function(){
    $(this).attr("placeholder", "");
    clearInterval(blinker);
});

$("#keyfob").on("blur", function(){
    $(previousElement).attr("placeholder", placeholderText);
        console.log(previousElement);
    blinker = setInterval(function(){
        $("#keyfob").attr("placeholder") == "" ? $("#keyfob").attr("placeholder", "Please click here for Key Fob scanning to work"): $("#keyfob").attr("placeholder", "");
    }, 1000);
});

$("#keyfob").blur();
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/czmwu470/)

Comment: Use `onfocus` event instead of click.

Comment: `focus` is more appropriate indeed. Because anyone might move through `input` elements using `TAB` key which won't fire the `click` event.

Comment: @Ashad Shanto, thanks for help and on more thing i want to blink the placeholder text on focusout so can you help me out with that?  -Bhairav

Comment: @Ashad Shanto,thanks for responding. For first time when i lauch the application it is working but the issue is still exist,when i am login in to my application and come back to home page the new issue is both the cursor and text are blinking by using the code which u have sent. can u please provide some other solution.

Comment: please do share your problem in a fiddle. So that I can view whats wrong.

Comment: I've tried it with the scenario you mentioned. Still it's working fine. Did you put your jQuery code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ // here })`;

Comment: ya i kept it inside the jQuery shanto but still it is not working for me and can u please create jsfiddle how it is still working fine for u .Thanxs

Comment: I've tested it on my local machine. From my main page I typed some text inside the textbox and then using `anchor` tag redirected to another page. But when I came back to the previous page it's working as usual.

Comment: try this fiddle. Put text inside the textbox and then click on `bing`. Then press the browser back button. You'll see the text is normal and not blinking. `Fiddle : ` http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/czmwu470/3/

Comment: thanxs shanto here it is working fine in jsfiddle shanto but it is not working in my application .